# How to use manually created fields in the same query with mysql?

Tags: mysql

This must be a super easy thing to do but i just couldn't neither get it done nor find in anywhere so asking here. This is what my `select` code looks like:

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT SUM(x) FROM a WHERE (...)) AS sum_x,
    (SELECT SUM(y) FROM b WHERE (...)) AS sum_y
FROM table
```

I wanna create one more field using `(sum_x - sum_y)` but when i attempt to do something like this

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT SUM(x) FROM a WHERE (...)) AS sum_x,
    (SELECT SUM(y) FROM b WHERE (...)) AS sum_y,
    (sum_x - sum_y) AS sum_c
FROM table
```

it gets angry with me and says `Unknown column 'sum_x' in 'field list'`.

What am i missing here?

Comment: Are your subqueries correlated with the outer query?

Comment: @GordonLinoff `sum_x` and `sum_y` are being calculated from corresponding tables by relating an id that matches in both `a`/`b` and `table` if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL in general does not allow you to refer to column aliases at the same level where you define them.  You would need to do this using a subquery:

```
select t.*, (sum_x - sum_y) as sum_c
from (SELECT *,
             (SELECT SUM(x) FROM a WHERE (...)) AS sum_x,
             (SELECT SUM(y) FROM b WHERE (...)) AS sum_y
      FROM table
     ) t;
```

However, MySQL tends to materialize subqueries so there is a performance penalty.  The overhead of materialization might be less than doing the subquery calculations twice:

```
      SELECT *,
             (SELECT SUM(x) FROM a WHERE (...)) AS sum_x,
             (SELECT SUM(y) FROM b WHERE (...)) AS sum_y,
             ((SELECT SUM(x) FROM a WHERE (...)) -
              (SELECT SUM(y) FROM b WHERE (...))
             ) as sum_c
      FROM table;
```

Doing the calculations only once is also easier to maintain and understand.

In MySQL, you could also do this:

```
      SELECT *,
             @sum_x := (SELECT SUM(x) FROM a WHERE (...)) AS sum_x,
             @sum_y := (SELECT SUM(y) FROM b WHERE (...)) AS sum_y,
             (@sum_x - @sum_y) as sum_c
      FROM table cross join
           (select @sum_x := 0, @sum_y := 0) const
```

MySQL does not *guarantee* that the last expression is evaluated after the assignments.  It does seem to consistently do so in practice.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers but this one seems most efficient as suggested it's doing the sum calculations only once. Thanks @Gordon_Linoff

Comment: I need a reference for "MySQL does not guarantee that the last expression is evaluated after the assignments" If you have please share with me thanks.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan . . . Here is the quote:  "However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined."  Read it in the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT SUM(x) FROM a WHERE (...)) AS sum_x,
    (SELECT SUM(y) FROM b WHERE (...)) AS sum_y,
    (SELECT SUM(x) FROM a WHERE (...) - (SELECT SUM(y) FROM b WHERE (...))) AS sum_c
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do it using subqueries instead of use alias

```
SELECT *,
    (SELECT SUM(x) FROM a WHERE (...)) AS sum_x,
    (SELECT SUM(y) FROM b WHERE (...)) AS sum_y,
    (
          (SELECT SUM(x) FROM a WHERE (....)) - (SELECT SUM(y) FROM b WHERE (...))
    ) AS sum_c
FROM table
```